# C# Dictionary Add vs Union

Tags: c#, data-structures

I just want to understand which one should I use.

I have a MessageListener in which I sometimes get just one item and sometimes I may get more than one items (could go upto 200 messages).

Method Signature is like below

```
   public void OnMessage(Message[] messages)
```

I am supposed to add each message to existing Messages data. Messages are stored in session memory.

```
  Dictionary<String,Message> existingMessages = (Dictionary<String,Message>) 
                                        Session.GetSessionData("key");
```

Is is better to add Message to the existingMessages one by one as below

```
foreach(Message msg in messages)
{
  existingMessages.Add(msg);
}
Session.AddData("key",existingMessages);
```

Is it better to create a map and merge with existing map as below

```
Dictionary<String,Message> newMap = new Dictionary<String,Message>(); 
foreach(Message msg in messages)
{
  newMap.Add(msg);
}
//combine with existing data
existingMessages.union(newMap);
//put the data back in session memory
Session.AddData("key",existingMessages);
```

Comment: These approaches will give you different results. `Add` will throw an exception for duplicated entries, `Union` will just take the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just wanting to send the combination of both back, there's no need to modify the structure of either. A LINQ-type method is good here because it produces a **proxy that represents the eventual enumeration of one set and then the other**.

Although since these are dictionaries, the idea of combining them is a little harder. What if there are duplicate keys? How do you deal with that - which one takes precedence?

If you're intending to produce a sequence of `KeyValuePair<string, Message>` then duplicate keys won't cause any issues. But if that's the case, keep in mind `Union()` might not do quite what you might expect - it will only append elements that aren't found in the first set. If you are Union-ing a sequence of `KeyValuePair<T,V>` it will use [ValueType.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the equality comparer, which has the following behavior:

> If none of the fields of the current instance and obj are reference types, the Equals method performs a byte-by-byte comparison of the two objects in memory. Otherwise, it uses reflection to compare the corresponding fields of obj and this instance.

You might want to use `Concat` instead.